# Javascript Console in QML output is sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, qml

I try to enable JavaScript console in QML. I tried Javascript Console example in QML book's git repository. But after entering first input as wrong value in console, the result is always undefined even if I input true value(like first input: a=b, enter, result is undefined, second input: 2+2, result is "undefined"). But when entering true value in console, it works well even if I input wrong value. When I try to modify javascript, it doesn't work. Is it possible to fix it? Thanks!

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "jsconsole.js" as Util
ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    title: qsTr("JSConsole")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 9
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            TextField {
                id: input
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                focus: true
                onAccepted: {
                    root.jsCall(input.text)
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Send")
                onClicked: {
                    root.jsCall(input.text)
                }
            }
        }
        Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: '#333'
                border.color: Qt.darker(color)
                opacity: 0.2
                radius: 2
            }
            ScrollView {
                id: scrollView
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 9
                ListView {
                    id: resultView
                    model: ListModel {
                        id: outputModel
                    }
                    delegate: ColumnLayout {
                        width: ListView.view.width
                        Label {
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            color: 'green'
                            text: "> " + model.expression
                        }
                        Label {
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            color: 'blue'
                            text: "" + model.result
                        }
                        Rectangle {
                            height: 1
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            color: '#333'
                            opacity: 0.2
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function jsCall(exp) {
        var data = Util.call(exp);
        outputModel.insert(0, data)
    }
}
```

jsconsole.js:

```
.pragma library

var scope = {
}

function call(msg) {
    var exp = msg.toString();
    console.log(exp)
    var data = {
        expression : msg
    }
    try {
        var fun = new Function('return (' + exp + ');');
        data.result = JSON.stringify(fun.call(scope), null, 2)
        console.log('scope: ' + JSON.stringify(scope, null, 2) + 'result: ' + result)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.toString())
        data.error = e.toString();
    }
    return data;
}
```

[Javascript console example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMsHc.png)